# Como se puedo hacer una busqueda con solo el año y el mes

Tags: mysql

Quiero hacer una query donde me sume unos montos en la tabla de ventas la cual esta tabla tiene:
No tarjeta, cantidad,  fecha de venta tipo timestamp osea que se guarda '2021-01-01'
la otra tabla llamada sta_cliente_compra_continua tiene :
No de tarjeta,año y mes

```
    SELECT 
    SC.TarjetaID,
    SC.MesesComprando,
   SUM(V.VentaTotal) MONTO,
  ROUND(SUM(V.VentaCantidad)) CANTIDAD
    FROM `sta_cliente_compra_continua` SC 
    JOIN venta V ON V.TarjetaID = SC.TarjetaID
    where V.VentaFecha BETWEEN CONCAT(SC.Ano-1,'-',SC.Mes,'-','01') AND CONCAT(SC.Ano,'-',SC.Mes,'-','01')
GROUP BY SC.TarjetaID
    ORDER BY SC.TarjetaID;
```

Obviamente esto esta mal, pero no se como relacionar las fechas para hacer las busquedas talvez con solo el año pero no se como plantearlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Elemento de lista

En mysql hay un función llamada YEAR utilizando el tipo de campo DATE que me puede traer los registro por año

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php
y utiliza la funcion MONTH para filtra el mes

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php

```
mysql> SELECT book_name,dt_of_pub,YEAR(dt_of_pub)
    -> FROM book_mast
    -> WHERE YEAR(dt_of_pub)>2003;
```

tu consulta seria algo así

```
SELECT 
    SC.TarjetaID,
    SC.MesesComprando,
    V.VentaFecha,
   SUM(V.VentaTotal) MONTO,
  ROUND(SUM(V.VentaCantidad)) CANTIDAD
    FROM `sta_cliente_compra_continua` SC 
    JOIN venta V ON V.TarjetaID = SC.TarjetaID
    where YEAR(V.VentaFecha) AND MONTH(V.VentaFecha)
GROUP BY SC.TarjetaID
    ORDER BY SC.TarjetaID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aprovecha la función [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Si por ejemplo, quieres obtener los registros en los que `v.VentaFecha` sean del año 2021, haces `where DATE_FORMAT(V.VentaFecha, '%Y') = '2021'`

Para cualquier otro caso, busca en el enlace que te he puesto